# PHP pcre regex to find content of curly brackets

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need PHP pcre regex to find content of all curly brackets...
Why is this regex doesn't work?

```
<?php

    $str = "test{it}test{/it}test";
    $ret = preg_match_all("#\{.?\}#u", $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

I expect `$matches` to contain `{it}` and `{/it}` - but it's empty....

Comment: `.?`  => 0 or 1 random character. Do you mean `.*?` (zero or more random characters, ungreedy)?

Comment: Change your regex to `.*?`.

Comment: `{.*?}` you do not need to escape `{` either

Comment: Personally, I'd use `/{[^}]+}/`, matching the opening and closing bracket and matching at least 1 non bracket char in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the version you are looking for: `{.*?}` with the `*` before the `?`

```
$re = "/{.*?}/"; 
$str = "test{it}test{/it}test"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

What your regex does:

```
\{.?\}
```

- Match the character “{” literally.
- Match any single character that is not a line break character between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.
- Match the character “}” literally.

---

What you want from your regex:

```
\{.*?\}
```

- Match the character “{” literally.
- Match any single character that is not a line break character between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed.
- Match the character “}” literally.

Comment: yes. you're right. i need my morning coffee.

Comment: well explained!